# Backbone JS, collection view empty for a second when fetching

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I bind the collection to a DOM element '#collection_view'.

When collection fetching data and update the view, the view changed to be EMPTY for a second and then filled with correct HTML.
In the collection there are addAll, addOne methods to append list element to the list.

How can I skip the empty, replace old HTML with new HTML directly?

Comment: Posting some code here would help. I'm assuming you are not manually clearing the div in the render() method of the view?

Comment: post code for your view, so we can see what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

This is how `fetch()` works.. it will *empty* the collection and *addAll* elements at once. I suppose you have a `this.$el.empty()` call (or something like) in your `addAll` event binding function. And what is happening is that the `$el` DOM element will be *cleaned* and after that *repopulated*.

If you want to *refresh* a collection instead of *reset* it you should check [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640095/backbone-js-collection-upsert).

Looks like [someone proposed to add this *soft update*](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/955) to the Backbone `Collection` but was denied by Backbone maintainers.